# PHP DOMDocument - Check for Updated XML File

Tags: php, domdocument

I currently have a script that looks something like this,

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'sync-img/data.xml' );

$user1 = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "user1" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
$user2 = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "user2" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
$user3 = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "user3" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
$user4 = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "user4" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
$user5 = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "user5" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
$user6 = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "user6" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

When the XML file gets new data, it would like the script, or page to refresh. Is there a way of putting the `$doc->load()` portion into a loop and checking to see if it was updated every few seconds, then force a refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Make a PHP Script which check for file Hash.

```
echo hash_file('md5', 'sync-img/data.xmlt');
```

On you're JavaScript store a Variable :

```
xmlHash = '<?php echo hash_file('md5', 'sync-img/data.xmlt');?>';
```

Than check periodically if **xmlHash** has changed :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    checkHash();
});

function checkHash()
{
    $.get('/get_xml_hash.php', function(data) {
        var newHash = data;
                if(newHash != xmlHash)
                     location.reload();
    });

    setTimeout("checkHash()",8000);
}
```

Or you can use [HTML5 Server-Sent Events](http://dsheiko.com/weblog/html5-and-server-sent-events/)